# Создание базы Новостного сайта и макета для вывода статей

Tags: php, mysql

Коллеги мой вопрос состоит из двух вопросов:

- 1. подскажите на какие таблицы лучше разделить базу MYSQL новостей и статей чтобы избежать проблем в будущем, что нужно учесть?
- 2. Второй вопрос логический и практический. Из базы данные будут выводиться на макет PHP, но как должна быть устроена база или как выводить данные чтобы чередовать текст и картинки при выводе на макете?

P.S.

Коллеги прощу вас не быть суровыми цензорами, и давать развернутые ответы и примеры.
Заранее большое спасибо!